# How to update a stream of React components?

Tags: reactjs, stream, components, render, renderer

I have a simple functional component

```
const Hello = (props) => <div>{props.name}</div>
```

How can I supply a stream of values to the `props` parameter and make the component update in reactive fashion, consuming the stream? So that every time the new value comes from the stream, I get the component updated with that value.

Basically I am looking for a way to manually re-render the component.

Comment: What do you mean by "*consuming the stream*"?

Comment: @Chris Tried to write it more clear.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Your component will update everytime you provide a new value for `props.name`.

Comment: @Chris I don't think it works outside the React lifecycle if I simply change my variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two basic methods:

1. Component rerendering, which you mentioned
2. State system: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

The second way could look like this:

```js
const Hello = (props) => <div>{props.name}</div>

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    source.on('event', name => {
      this.setState({name});
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return <Hello name=this.state.name/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know any example with streams?

Comment: source is an analog of stream here as you can listen to events for any stream
basically stream is an event producing entity

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've found slight modification without calling the `setState`: http://codepen.io/dmitriz/pen/rmvOjQ?editors=0010

Comment: I understand that `forceUpdate()` is more reliable.